# Spectrum of a binary markov transition matrix

Tags: matrix-analysis, markov-chains, sparse-matrices

I would like to know if there are any special analytic expressions or fast numerical methods to get the spectrum for the transition matrix corresponding to a **Markovian binary process (Bernoulli process with history dependence)**.
For example, a process that depends only on the past 3 time steps, the transition matrix has the following form:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    1-\omega_{000} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1-\omega_{100} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      \omega_{000} & 0 & 0 & 0 &   \omega_{100} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1-\omega_{001} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1-\omega_{101} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 &   \omega_{001} & 0 & 0 & 0 &   \omega_{101} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1-\omega_{010} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1-\omega_{110} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 &   \omega_{010} & 0 & 0 & 0 &   \omega_{110} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1-\omega_{011} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1-\omega_{111} \\
    0 & 0 & 0 &   \omega_{011} & 0 & 0 & 0 &   \omega_{111} 
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
    p_{000}\\
    p_{001}\\
    p_{010}\\
    p_{011}\\
    p_{100}\\
    p_{101}\\
    p_{110}\\
    p_{111}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    p_{000}\\
    p_{001}\\
    p_{010}\\
    p_{011}\\
    p_{100}\\
    p_{101}\\
    p_{110}\\
    p_{111}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\omega$ is the probability of 1 in the next time step, and $p$ are probability mass over all possible histories (of length 3 in this case).

There's a nice structure to the matrix, so I am hoping that it is a known form with solutions.

Comment: There was a question here on MO about a matrix with a very similar structure (two stacked blocks with $D \otimes vector$), but unfortunately I can't find it now. :( I don't recall any conclusive answer on that thread, though.